# Having trouble wrapping my head around the "!=" operator and "and" & "or" keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x

So say, in a while loop...

```
var = input()
while var =! "A" and var =! "B":
    var = input()
```

Here I want it to loop until the user inputs **either** A *or* B. Now logically, it makes more sense to use "or" instead of "and". But "and" seems to be the one that works. I'm trying to wrap my head around why. I want to get this logic step by step, for both "and" and "or" keywords.

So say the user inputs "C". The while loop will check var does not equal A which is true, and then check if var does not equal B which is also true. So wouldn't that run the loop?

Now using "or" instead, it will check if var is not A and then check if var is not B, if it satisfies either requirements, it will run the loop. So wouldn't "or" be the one that should work?

Comment: Think about what happens if you set `var = 'A'`...

Comment: `while var not in ("A", "B")`

Comment: Why `or` _make more sense_ over `and`?

Comment: "So wouldn't that run the loop?" - yes. It's *supposed* to run the loop. The loop is supposed to run until you get an input that both isn't "A" **and** isn't "B".

Comment: `var =! "A"` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Did you look for similar questions and decide that this was the same as one question but not the same as another and so conclude it wasn't a duplicate? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you certainly meant `!=`, not `=!`. Secondly, read on de Morgan's laws (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

As for your example, let's consider what happens when `var == 'A'`. From there we have your loop condition, which states that `var != 'A' and var != 'B'`. From there, we have `'A' != 'A' and 'A' != 'B'`. Consequently, we have `False and True`, which gives `False` and the loop does not run.

If we had `or` instead of `and`, we would get: `False or True`, which gives `True` and the program would loop.

The negations might have confused you. Per de Morgan's laws `var != 'A' and var != 'B'` is equivalent to `!(var == 'A' or var == 'B')`

Answer (score 0):

What you said is ture. If you input some value C that is destinct from A and B the loop will run. If you want to run the loop if either A or B is the input then you should use or.